# Linux Mint 17 does not mount WD My Passport 4TB USB

Tags: filesystems

I have a  WD My Passport 4.0 TB USB with GPT partition, that was used in a 2013 MacBook Pro.
My Linux Mint 17 is "Unable to mount location  Can't mount file".
Linux Mint "Disks" shows the 4 TB drive as having GUID Partition Table, partition type Apple HFS/HFS+ and contents unknown.
GParted shows it as  having 3.64 TiB partition with unknown file system and another segment of space at the end as unallocated 1.00 MiB

I would like to recover the missing 0.35 TiB and then maybe install a partition my Linux can mount. What's on it now does not matter.
I only want to use the drive for storage .

Answer (score 1):

There is no missing 0.35 TiB.

TiB are measured using multiples of 2<sup>n</sup> (2<sup>10</sup> = 1024), and TB are measured using multiples of 10<sup>n</sup> (10<sup>3</sup> = 1000):

- 3.64 TiB = 3.64*1024*1024*1024*1024 = 4002222325104 bytes
- 4 TB = 4*1000*1000*1000*1000 = 4000000000000 bytes

The (relatively) small GB discrepancy can be found by dividing the 4 x 10<sup>12</sup> by multiples of 1024:

- 4000000000000 bytes / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = 3.63798... which after reasonable rounding is approximately 3.64.

What you will need to do though is to reformat the 4TB partition as ext4 (or NTFS/ex-FAT if you must). This is because the Linux kernel cannot write to journalled HFS/HFS+ filesystems - although I believe there is a commercial extension available from Paragon if you want to consider that.

Comment: Thank you both for your kind answers. But if I do as you both suggest and reformat to ext4, for instance, will the GPT partition table stay on the drive or will it be replaced by something else/be changed?

Comment: The GPT partition table will remain unchanged, but the contents of the previous filesystem (Apple HFS/HFS+) will be erased. You can erase and recreate the GPT if you want to, since there's only the one 4TB partition.

Comment: Excellent assistance! Thank you both Christopher and roaima, will do as suggested.